# WebView in FlipViewItem - WebView does not accept any gestures

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml

I've put a WebView inside of a FlipViewItem. The problem seems to be that in WP 8.1, the WebView does not get the gestures (presumably because they're absorbed by the FlipView). The desired result is to be able to scroll vertically and tap in the WebView but also to be able scroll horizontally for the FlipView (even if just in a limited area on the horizontal edges). Is there any solution or workaround for this?

```
 <StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Name="postTitle" Background="Transparent">
        <TextBlock Name="ContentArea" Text="" FontSize="18" Margin="10, 5, 10, 0" TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="White"/>
        <TextBlock Name="SubArea" Text="" FontSize="16" Margin="10, 0, 10, 10" TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords" Foreground="White"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <FlipView Name="swipeArea" Height="460" Margin="0" Padding="0" SelectedIndex="1" SelectionChanged="swipeArea_SelectionChanged">
        <FlipViewItem Name="oneItem">
        </FlipViewItem>
        <FlipViewItem Name="mainFlipViewItem">
            <Grid>
                <ProgressRing Name="progRing" Foreground="White" Margin="0,25,0,0" Background="Transparent" Visibility="Collapsed" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                <WebView Name="InterWindow" Height="460" Visibility="Collapsed" DefaultBackgroundColor="#5E5E5E"></WebView>
                <ScrollViewer Name="Scrollster" ZoomMode="Enabled" MinZoomFactor="1" MaxZoomFactor="8" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                    <Image Name="WebWindow" Height="420" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                    </Image>
                </ScrollViewer>
            </Grid>
        </FlipViewItem>
        <FlipViewItem Name="threeItem">
        </FlipViewItem>
    </FlipView>
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I just found one workaround. I've added this to the WebView control:

```
Canvas.ZIndex="1000"
```

I can then set the width of the WebView control to something *just* slimmer than the FlipView itself, and then I should be good.